# Что значит эта часть кода?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который работает следующим образом: при нажатии на иконку музыка включается при нажатии 2 раз выключается. 
Вот сам скрипт:

```
function togglePlay(video) {

  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];

  if (audio) {

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg";
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg";
    }
  }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, что значит `[0]` возле `(audio)`. Для чего он нужен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вызов

```
document.getElementsByTagName("audio")
```

Возвращает массив всех элементов `audio` c вашей страницы а `[0]` обращется к первому элементу этого массива (элементу с индексом **0**), таким образом это выражение вернет первый элемент `audio` с Вашей страницы

Для особенных случаев у массива есть метод `shift()` который возвращает первый элемент(голову) и удаляет его из массива а так же метод `pop()` который действует так же с последним элементом(хвостом)

Comment: Спасибо, а где еще можно использовать такой ход? То есть, есть какие-то живые примеры, наглядные, кроме этого?

Comment: @AsasSas Вы про обращение по индексу, поиск элементов по типу тега или аудио?

Comment: про индекс `[0]`

Comment: @AsasSas повсеместно, где это приемлемо =)

Comment: @Stranget in the Q, спасибо!

Comment: @AsasSas всегда пожалуйста